# Sharepoint list field validation

Tags: c#, validation, sharepoint-2010

I have created List called "CarInfo". suppose i have booked 12:00am to 1:00am and again another person have booked same time and car also. Here I need validation for fields another person should not booked same time.How

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of cars, and a separate calendar list of bookings, you can [configure the calendar as a "resource reservation" calendar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-HA101810595.aspx).

(I didn't know about this, but it looks like a handy feature.)

Edit: on second look, it looks like this uses a web-wide "Resources" list, rather than you being able to point it at your "CarInfo" list. If you can be flexible and put your cars in the "Resources" list, you should still be able to use this.

The alternative is to write a custom list item receiver that checks, on Item Creating/Updating, that the selected time doesn't overlap with existing items, and Cancels the event if it does.

Comment: I have created 2 lists : 1. CarInfo

Comment: I have created 2 lists : 1. CarInfo(Custom List)  2.Car Booking(Calendar List). After I created columns like CarName and CarNumber.when I select Car Name carNumber its Automatically comes but what my requirement is when i can select car name , start Time and End Time.Suppose Car Name is Car1 , Start Time is 1:00pm and End Time is 2;00Pm. another User can login and add same car and timings.if another user can give same things it wont allow that fields.

Comment: I'd suggest that you follow the guide I linked, and put copies of your car names in the Resources list. It'll mean having duplicate data, but it will mean you can use the built-in resource booking functionality rather than having to write custom code.